# Methods to detect metal buildup on a magnet?

Tags: hall-effect, metal

So far I have been exploring **Hall-effect sensors and basic metal detection.**

The application for my required need has limited space, needs to be small enough to fit in a palm and the simpler the design the better.

*Apart from hall-effect sensors and basic metal detecting circuits are, there any other electronic circuits that work effectively in a small environment and in a simple manner?*

*Are there any electronically related aspects to take into consideration with metal detection on a small scale?*

Comment: Are you trying to design something that detects metal build up in something like a gearbox to give an early indication of imminent failure?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: In the past I wound balanced coils around a magnet with an overall excitation coil that was attached to an oscillator. I used the balanced coil output amplitude to detect the iron particle build up over time. Only one magnet pole was subjected to iron particle build up. The device was in a circulating oil feed in the sump. When the machine started it blew away the filings and when the machine stopped the particles built up over a few hours and that was measured.

Comment: @Andy aka - Fantastic insight - are there any specific things to note with the type of coil, consistency in shape, interferences of nearby metal surfaces ? How accurate was the readings you found or did were you using a discrete (boolean?) Signal?

Comment: It was back in the 1980s and was an evolving prototype that never got used in bigger production - the output was analogue and was just logged by an MCU to deliver readings for post analysis.

Comment: @Andyaka - Thank you, very informative -- I'll keep at it.